# ElasticSearch bool query return null immediately after insert data

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, nest

I insert multi objects in my index and when I immediately get query from index after inserting data my my output is null
but after almost 8 hour when I retry that query my result have some content

my query is :

```
GET myIndex/_search
{
  "size": 1, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "identifier": {
              "value": "597713-2"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "organizationUnitCode": {
              "value": "00001"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

this is my index setting:

```
{
  "myIndex" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1633957331203",
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "V_MtNZ57S4CFmlKwS_0wyA",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "7020099"
        },
        "provided_name" : "myIndex"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please share myIndex/_setting?pretty response

Comment: @hamidbayat I update my question and add settings

Comment: the document would be searchable after `refresh` process happen. the default setting sets to 1 seconds. obviously you didn't change the default setting. but to be sure set index.refresh_interval to 1s

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch is near a real-time engine, which means that if you index and immediately try to query, it will not work (it could take at least one second to make the content searchable, but the accurate time depends on your environment and configuration).

For more information: [Elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/near-real-time.html)

Comment: I try for qurying after refresh interval but i don't get proper result